# Line bundle on a complex torus whose Chern class is given.

Tags: complex-geometry

Let $\mathbb C$ be a standard complex plane, $\Lambda=\mathbb Z+i\mathbb Z$ be a lattice in $\mathbb C$, then we can get a torus $T=\mathbb C/\Lambda$, when $T$ is equipped with a standard Kähler metric $h=dz\otimes d\bar z$, then its associated Kähler form is $\omega=\frac{i}{2}dz\wedge d\bar z$. According to Chern's book *complex manifolds* p.65, Formula 7.30, the Kähler class $[\omega]$ is integral (then $\omega$ is called a Hodge metric), i.e. $[\omega]\in H^{1,1}(X,\mathbb Z)$. Then using Lefschetz theorem on (1,1) class, we get there is a holomorphic line bundle $L$ over $T$ such that its Chern class is exactly $[\omega]$. But I find it hard to construct $L$ explictly, since we should give $T$ a covering and the transition functions between them, is there a canonical choice of covering?

Comment: one relevant reference is  Herbert Lange's Abelian Varieties over the Complex Numbers, section 1.2.

Comment: @Invariance, thanks for pointing out this reference to me, in section 1.2.2, the author seems do not choose a covering, but uses a factor of automorphy.